# Next.js: How to restore scroll state on reload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

#### Description

I'm struggling with something I've implemented, which is basically a sticky header that depends on a useEffect that watched its scrollYOffset state, but once I reload the page, it does not get to identify until I scroll again.

#### Screenshots

After reload
[image: fixed header - after reload]
After scrolling
[image: fixed header - scroll state]

#### Source Code

```
const Header = () => {
  const [isSticky, setSticky] = useState(false)

  useSSRLayoutEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'scroll',
      () => {
        if (window.pageYOffset > 54) {
          setSticky(true)
        } else {
          setSticky(false)
        }
      },
      { passive: true }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <header
        className={cx(
          'fixed top-0 z-10 flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center transition-all',
          isSticky
            ? 'bg-black bg-opacity-60 backdrop-blur'
            : 'bg-transparent pt-4'
        )}
      >
        ...
      </header>
    </>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to invoke the function that you've passed to the scroll event handler when the component is mounted, too.

This is easiest done by abstracting the logic into a separate function, and invoking it both on scroll and when the effect callback runs:

```
useSSRLayoutEffect(() => {
  const onScroll = () => {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 54) {
      setSticky(true);
    } else {
      setSticky(false);
    }
  };

  // Run logic when scroll event is fired
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => onScroll(), { passive: true });

  // Run logic when component is ready
  onScroll();
}, []);
```

However, if you have to wait for the browser to run the layout first to ensure you have the final scroll position, then you need to invoke the function in `useEffect` instead:

```
const onScroll = () => {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 54) {
    setSticky(true);
  } else {
    setSticky(false);
  }
};

useSSRLayoutEffect(() => {
  // Run logic when scroll event is fired
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => onScroll(), { passive: true });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // Run logic when layout is finalized
  onScroll();
});
```